# Elixir's `mix format` configuration options

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I'm trying to find a list a configurable options for mix format to put in the formatter config file, but I can't for the life of me find it.  It's not in the mix format docs or anywhere else I've looked.  Anyone know where I can find this information?

Comment: Maybe this article could helps: https://medium.com/blackode/code-formatter-the-big-feature-in-elixir-v1-6-0-f6572061a4ba

Answer (score 8):

It turns out that `mix format` does not have a lot of options to set, and what you see on the [mix docs page](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Format.html) is exactly what you get.  It seems there are not a breadth of settings to make it more opinionated.

Answer (score 3):

You should read the docs: [Formatting Options](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Format.html#module-formatting-options)

There are plenty of guides to get you started online as well, for example: [Everything you need to know about Elixir's new formatter](https://devonestes.herokuapp.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-elixirs-new-formatter)

Comment: As I said, I have read the docs.  I was expecting a lot more fine-tuning of format, like something I would get with a JS linter.  It's basically a hand full of things you can set, and then manually specifying what functions you want to wrap with parens.

Answer (score 2):

When you need a bunch of options to fine tune the format of your project, then try one of these tools https://github.com/h4cc/awesome-elixir#code-analysis, we are currently using *credo*.