# Configure indentation in mix formatter

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

In my Phoenix app I have the following code:

```
  attrs           = %{"name" => "mat", "color" => "blue"}
  conn            = post(conn, Routes.session_path(conn, :create), player: attrs)
  expected_player = %Player{name: "mat", color: "blue"}
```

the problem is that when I run `mix.format` task it updates it to something like this:

```
  attrs = %{"name" => "mat", "color" => "blue"}
  conn = post(conn, Routes.session_path(conn, :create), player: attrs)
  expected_player = %Player{name: "mat", color: "blue"}
```

Which for me is less readable. Is there any way of configure mix formatter to not remove my indentation?

Comment: [This does not appear to be possible](https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-customize-the-formatter/14491/3) because the formatter configuration options are limited.

Comment: More information [here](https://medium.com/blackode/code-formatter-the-big-feature-in-elixir-v1-6-0-f6572061a4ba) and at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50958098/elixirs-mix-format-configuration-options)

Comment: You can exclude the entire file from the list of automatically formatted, but please note that the former way (equal signs in the same column) is a code smell since it has a drawback: when the new one [long] value is added, equal signs should be all adjusted leading to the `diff` including several lines that were not in fact changed. No one OSS project would accept this style of formatting, so you’d better get accustomed to the proper style suggested by `formatter`.